# Java "cannot assign value to final variable"

Tags: java, variables

```
public class Quiz {

    private static void homePage() {
        JFrame homePage = new JFrame("QUIZ");
        Container c = homePage.getContentPane();
        homePage.setVisible(true);
        homePage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        homePage.setBounds(600,180,700,400);
        homePage.setResizable(false);
        homePage.setContentPane(c);

        JLabel benvenuto = new JLabel("Benvenuto!");
        benvenuto.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        benvenuto.setBounds(265,0,180,120);
        benvenuto.setOpaque(true);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Inserisci il tuo nome:");
        label1.setBounds(215,100,120,100);
        label1.setOpaque(true);

        JTextArea areaNome = new JTextArea();
        areaNome.setEditable(true);
        areaNome.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        areaNome.setBounds(345,142,120,20);
        javax.swing.border.Border borderP = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        areaNome.setBorder(borderP);

        JLabel labelStarting = new JLabel();
        labelStarting.setBounds(230,230,280,120);
        labelStarting.setForeground(Color.RED);

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Inizia");
        startButton.setBounds(280,200,120,50);
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String gt1 = areaNome.getText();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Quiz.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                labelStarting.setText("Preparati "+gt1+", il gioco sta per iniziare.");

                JFrame quizPage = new JFrame("QUIZ");
                quizPage.setBounds(573,150,750,450);
                quizPage.setVisible(true);
                quizPage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                quizPage.setResizable(false);
                Container c2 = quizPage.getContentPane();
                quizPage.setContentPane(c2);

                JLabel domanda1 = new JLabel("1) Qual è la capitale d'Italia?");
                domanda1.setBounds(0,0,280,120);

                JLabel domanda2 = new JLabel("2) Quanto fa 2^8?");
                domanda2.setBounds(0,55,280,120);   

                JLabel domanda3 = new JLabel("3) Quando è stata scoperta l'America da Colombo?");
                domanda3.setBounds(0,110,380,120);

                JLabel domanda4 = new JLabel("4) Dove si trova l'Empire State Building?");
                domanda4.setBounds(0,165,280,120);

                JLabel domanda5 = new JLabel("5) Qual è il nome dell'autore della Divina Commedia?");
                domanda5.setBounds(0,220,380,120);

                JLabel labelNull2 = new JLabel();
                labelNull2.setBounds(230,230,280,120);

                JTextArea r1 = new JTextArea();
                r1.setBounds(320,50,120,20);
                javax.swing.border.Border border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
                r1.setBorder(border1);

                JTextArea r2 = new JTextArea();
                r2.setBounds(320,105,120,20);
                javax.swing.border.Border border2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
                r2.setBorder(border2);

                JTextArea r3 = new JTextArea();
                r3.setBounds(320,160,120,20);
                javax.swing.border.Border border3 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
                r3.setBorder(border3);

                JTextArea r4 = new JTextArea();
                r4.setBounds(320,217,120,20);
                javax.swing.border.Border border4 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
                r4.setBorder(border4);

                JTextArea r5 = new JTextArea();
                r5.setBounds(320,270,120,20);
                javax.swing.border.Border border5 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
                r5.setBorder(border5);

                JButton br1 = new JButton("Conferma");
                br1.setBounds(475,49,120,25);

                JButton br2 = new JButton("Conferma");
                br2.setBounds(475,105,120,25);

                JButton br3 = new JButton("Conferma");
                br3.setBounds(475,160,120,25);

                JButton br4 = new JButton("Conferma");
                br4.setBounds(475,216,120,25);

                JButton br5 = new JButton("Conferma");
                br5.setBounds(475,270,120,25);

                JLabel lp1 = new JLabel();
                lp1.setBounds(635,45,100,30);
                lp1.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

                JLabel lp2 = new JLabel();
                lp2.setBounds(635,103,100,30);
                lp2.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

                JLabel lp3 = new JLabel();
                lp3.setBounds(635,158,100,30);
                lp3.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

                JLabel lp4 = new JLabel();
                lp4.setBounds(635,213,100,30);
                lp4.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

                JLabel lp5 = new JLabel();
                lp5.setBounds(635,269,100,30);
                lp5.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

                JLabel lp11 = new JLabel();
                lp11.setBounds(635,45,100,30);
                lp11.setForeground(Color.RED);

                JLabel lp22 = new JLabel();
                lp22.setBounds(635,103,100,30);
                lp22.setForeground(Color.RED);

                JLabel lp33 = new JLabel();
                lp33.setBounds(635,158,100,30);
                lp33.setForeground(Color.RED);

                JLabel lp44 = new JLabel();
                lp44.setBounds(635,213,100,30);
                lp44.setForeground(Color.RED);

                JLabel lp55 = new JLabel();
                lp55.setBounds(635,269,100,30);
                lp55.setForeground(Color.RED);

                int number = 0;

                br1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        String sr1 = r1.getText();
                        if(sr1.equals("Roma")||sr1.equals("roma")) {
                            lp1.setText("ESATTO");
                            number += 1;
                        }else {
                            lp11.setText("ERRATO");
                        }
                    }
                });

                br2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        String sr2 = r2.getText();
                        if(sr2.equals("256")) {
                            lp2.setText("ESATTO");
                        }else {
                            lp22.setText("ESATTO");
                        }
                    }
                });

                br3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        String sr3 = r3.getText();
                        if(sr3.equals("1492")) {
                            lp3.setText("ESATTO");
                        }else {
                            lp33.setText("ERRATO");
                        }
                    }
                });

                br4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        String sr4 = r4.getText();
                        if(sr4.equals("New York")||sr4.equals("new york")) {
                            lp4.setText("ESATTO");
                        }else {
                            lp44.setText("ERRATO");
                        }
                    }
                });

                br5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        String sr5 = r5.getText();
                        if(sr5.equals("Dante")||sr5.equals("dante")) {
                            lp5.setText("ESATTO");
                        }else {
                            lp55.setText("ERRATO");
                        }
                    }
                });

                JLabel risultato = new JLabel("Il tuo punteggio finale è: "+number+"/5");
                risultato.setBounds(10,320,300,60);


                c2.add(domanda1);
                c2.add(domanda2);
                c2.add(domanda3);
                c2.add(domanda4);
                c2.add(domanda5);
                c2.add(r1);
                c2.add(r2);
                c2.add(r3);
                c2.add(r4);
                c2.add(r5);
                c2.add(br1);
                c2.add(br2);
                c2.add(br3);
                c2.add(br4);
                c2.add(br5);
                c2.add(lp1);
                c2.add(lp2);
                c2.add(lp3);
                c2.add(lp4);
                c2.add(lp5);
                c2.add(lp11);
                c2.add(lp22);
                c2.add(lp33);
                c2.add(lp44);
                c2.add(lp55);
                c2.add(risultato);
                c2.add(labelNull2);
            }
        });



        JLabel labelNull = new JLabel();



        c.add(benvenuto);
        c.add(label1);
        c.add(areaNome);
        c.add(startButton);
        c.add(labelStarting);
        c.add(labelNull);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        homePage();
    }
}
```

Before the Action Listener of the button br1 there is the variable (int number = 0;), it will be increased if 9 lines down but it give me an error:local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final... if i let the number to final (final int number = 0;) the increase give me another error: cannot assign a value to final variable number... where's the error??

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title than _"Could u help me?"_.

Comment: Sorry for this... what i have to do in this chase?

Comment: Right now, we can`t. Do as Michael said. Also reducing the code to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org "That's an acronym for Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example") would help a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry again, first day in this site

Answer (score 0):

define your `number` variable outside of `homepage` method, that will work fine without being final

**EDIT**
first remove this `int number = 0;` from `homepage` method, then defined number outside method:

```
public class Quiz {
   static int number = 0;

    private static void homePage() {
    //homepage body
    }
}
```

this should make it compile

now few comments

1. make your method non-static, i know this is just you playing around, but static methods and variables are signs of bad coding.
2. what your number is actually doing? only place where yo are using it, is here

   `JLabel risultato = new JLabel("Il tuo punteggio finale è: "+number+"/5");`

   if your number will change this label won't be updated, to make it work, you need to update text inside your label

Comment: @user3721668 if you have `static int number` defined outside `homepage` method, and you are not defining variable with same name inside homepage method, this means you are not building properly

Comment: could u write how to do this pls?

Answer (score -1):

A trick I learned is to make an array with 1 element. This way, you can do this:

```
final int[] number = { 0 };

number[0] = 4; // random number picked
```

Now you can set a value to the final variable :)

Comment: with ur method it gives me this:

Comment: final int[] number = { 0 };

number[0] = 1   --->  System.out.prinln(number);-->[@e415ac2...what's?

Comment: @user3721668 try to print the first number in the array, like: System.out.println(number[0]); or System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));

Nim, it's not misleading, it's the compromise for a mutable integer.